Facing Issues with Mutual TLS Configuration for Specific Routes in Azure Application Gateway
We need to support two APIs accessible through the domain device-api-server.com using Azure Application Gateway:
Bootstrap API
Path: /api/bootStrap
Request Method: POST
Authentication: No authentication required.
Handshake API
Path: /api/v2/handshake
Request Method: POST
Authentication: Requires mutual TLS (SSL validation).
Current Setup:
We created two listeners in the API Gateway configuration:
Bootstrap-Listener:
Listens on device-api-server.com.
No certificate validation is required.
Path Forwarding Rules:
Requests to /api/bootStrap are forwarded to the backend pool onboarding-service.
Requests to /api/v2/handshake are routed to the Handshake Listener.


Handshake-Listener:
Validates the TLS profile for mutual authentication.
Forwards requests to the backend pool onboarding-service.


Issue:
When a request is sent to the Handshake API via the Handshake Listener, the response is:
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <TITLE>Length Required</TITLE>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>
    <h2>Length Required</h2>
    <hr>
    <p>HTTP Error 411. The request must be chunked or have a content length.</p>
  </BODY>
</HTML>

Looks like Content-length header is getting dropped when Path Rule "/api/v2/handshake" is forwarding the request to Handshake-Listener"
Requirement:
How can we configure Azure Application Gateway to ensure:
The Bootstrap API remains accessible without authentication.
The Handshake API performs mutual TLS validation while avoiding the HTTP 411 "Length Required" error
